# How to create c# windows service with multi threading to get sql table data

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, windows-services

I have created a c# winows service to reead data from SQL server queue table and execute a stored procedure based on the queueId from queue table.

My Quetable structure is as below

[image]

Now I have a service to pick top 1 QueueID from this table and will do the operation in service using the JobId. Once service picked the queueId it will delete that QueueId from this table.

I have set interval of 2 minutes. So the service will every 2 minute an pick jobs one by one from Queue table and process.

Please find the below code I am using.

```
   public bool StartTask()
    {
        
        int queue_id = 0;
        int job_id = 0;
        DataTable dt;
        Stopwatch sWatch = new Stopwatch();
        TimeSpan tSpan;
        Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
       
        try
        {
            timer.Stop();
            waitHandle.WaitOne();
            dt = GetQueueID();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                queue_id = (int)dr[0];
                job_id = (int)dr[1];
               
                DeleteJobQueue(queue_id, job_id);
            }
            waitHandle.Set();
            timer.Stop();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                sWatch.Restart();
                queue_id = (int)dr[0];
                job_id = (int)dr[1];
                
                    ProcessJob(Convert.ToInt32(job_id));
                
                }
            dt = null;

            timer.Dispose();
            log.logger.Debug(string.Format("Timer Object is now disposed and refreshed at {0}", DateTime.Now));
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            //providing the time in miliseconds
            timer.Interval = 120000;
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Start();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dt = null;
            
           
        }
        finally
        {
            dt = null;
           

        }
        
        return true;
    }
private void ProcessJob(int job_id)
    {
        
        DataTable dtJobDetails = GetJobDetails(job_id);
        int Status = Convert.ToInt32(dtJobDetails.Rows[0]["Status"].ToString());
        int Retrycount = Convert.ToInt32(dtJobDetails.Rows[0]["Retry"].ToString());
        if (Status == 3 && Retrycount <=3)
            ProcessJob(job_id);
        
        
    }
```

Here, the service will get QueueIDs one by one and process it.
Scenario is when multiple users submit their job, other has to wait till first job get finished.

Is there any possibility to make it multi thread so that servce can pick all the jobs in the queue table and process simultaneously without affecting the performance.

Now as a solution I have created multiple instances of same service and running it. Is it the correct approach?

Comment: `Now as a solution I have created multiple instances of same service and running it. Is it the correct approach?`. Yes I did the same in certain scenarios. The critical path is that each process should not handle the same QueueID. Use a lock hint in your SQL like `with (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, READPAST)`

Comment: You want your cake and your pie too.  How can you run more processes in parallel and not effect performance?  What you really want is to decrease the run time and of course this will make the CPU utilization go up.

Comment: How should anyone know if it is "correct approach"? Some processes benefit from threading, some do not. You are the only one that knows what your process does; you are the only one that can test and evaluate the results. Your process might benefit from additional threads - and there might be a point where increasing the number of threads decreases the overall performance. Test it.

Comment: @AlexB. Thank you for the response..

Comment: @AlexB. When I tried below query in same window, both provided same queid. How can i test it in sql lock is properly working.
select top 1 jobid from table1 with (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, READPAST) order by JobID desc

select top 1 jobid from table1 with (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, READPAST) order by JobID desc

Comment: You need a Status column with values like `Initial`, `InProgress` and `Done`. In your query where you get th ID you need an Update like `UPDATE table SET Status = 'InProgress' OUTPUT inserted.JobID WHERE JobID = SELECT (TOP 1 FROM table (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, READPAST) WHERE Status = 'Initial' ORDER BY JobID desc)`